# AS3 Flash Builder Error Incorrect number of arguments

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

i make music player and use FileFilter for filter mp3 and .. files .
this is my code :

```
<![CDATA[
            import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
            import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
            import flash.media.Sound;
            import flash.media.SoundChannel;
            import flash.media.SoundTransform;
            import flash.net.URLRequest;

            private var sound:Sound;
            private var songLength:String;
            private var soundChannel:SoundChannel;
            [Bindable]
            private var readyToPlay:Boolean = false;
            [Bindable]
            private var playing:Boolean = false;
            private var file:File;
            private var filter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Music", "*.mp3;*.ogg");

            protected function browse_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
                file = new File();
                file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelect);
                file.browseForDirectory("Open",[filter]);
            }
```

error in this line :

file.browseForDirectory("Open",[filter]);

> 1137: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 1.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly says what's wrong. You always can open a documentation related to your code and check the required arguments: [Adobe File class documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#browseForDirectory())

In your case you must remove the second argument:

```
file.browseForDirectory("Open"); // assuming that Open is a dirname
```

If you want to use FileFilter, then use other method:

```
file.browseForOpen("Open",[filter]);
```